# HTML and css for div inside a div and a div left and right

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and HTML (front End Developing). I am trying to replicate the requirement as in the image. I have tried the below code. But not even near the requirement. Can anyone please suggest how can i achieve the exact replicate of the below requirement?[image]

so the left rectangular box should contain and the right side there should be some text about it as shown in the image.

Please find below for the code:

```css
#inner{
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right : 20%;
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    background-color: white;
    border : 1px solid black;
}
#outer{
    background-color: rgb(238,238,238);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#right #para2{
    width:50%;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            <div id="wraper">
                <div id="left">
                     <div id="para1">
                         Delhi is a crowded city. There are very few rich people who travel by their
                         own vehicles. The majority of the people cannot afford to hire a taxi or a 
                         three-wheeler. They have to depend on D.T.C. buses, which are the cheapest 
                         mode of conveyance. D.T.C. buses are like blood capillaries.
                     </div>

                </div>
                 <div id="right">
                     <div id="para2">
                         Delhi is a crowded city. There are very few rich people who travel by their
                         own vehicles. The majority of the people cannot afford to hire a taxi or a 
                         three-wheeler. They have to depend on D.T.C. buses, which are the cheapest 
                         mode of conveyance. D.T.C. buses are like blood capillaries.
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I know i am no where near, but i am really having tough time on applying css here. I am pretty new to CSS an din learning stages. Can any please provide a soolutiion for this please?

Explanation: The outer div is the portion in Grey.
The inner div is the portion in white.
The div left is for the images on the left.
The div is for the text on the right side for the image.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: If your sections are always going to be in the image - text format, then I don't see why not using a standard html table to achieve this.

Comment: Yes . Its always a image - text format @Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.allParent{
background-color:gray;
padding:10% 20%;
}
.titleAll{
  width:100%;
  padding-top:5px;
  background-color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
.titleAll h4{
  color:gray;
  margin:0;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:#fff;
  text-align:left;
}

.parent .child {
  padding-right: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width:50%;
  font-size:80%;
  
}

.parent .child:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="allParent">
<div class="titleAll">
  <h4>Cats description</h4>
<div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">
     <img src="http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-Schrodinger-as-a-kitten..png"  style="width:100%">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Cats are similar in anatomy to the other felids, with a strong flexible body, quick reflexes, sharp retractable claws, and teeth adapted to killing small prey. Cat senses fit a crepuscular and predatory ecological niche. Cats can hear sounds too faint or too high in frequency for human ears, such as those made by mice and other small animals.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="titleAll">
  <h4>Cats description</h4>
<div>
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">
     <img src="http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-Schrodinger-as-a-kitten..png"  style="width:100%">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Cats are similar in anatomy to the other felids, with a strong flexible body, quick reflexes, sharp retractable claws, and teeth adapted to killing small prey. Cat senses fit a crepuscular and predatory ecological niche. Cats can hear sounds too faint or too high in frequency for human ears, such as those made by mice and other small animals.</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a suggestion.  using bootstrap classes .https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion here. But this should be only in the white portion . How do i make the outer grey div in this code please?

Comment: This looks great thanks a lot for the edit. But How can we remove the grey part in between two images and make it look like its from a single page? @FarhadBagherlo

Comment: I edited. remove       **border-bottom:solid 4px gray** in **'.parent**  div

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot made some modification and it loks great as expected. thanks a lot for the quick solution. I am trying to keep a heading on top of image text with full width anddifferent background color. Cann you please suggest an edit for this please? @FarhadBagherlo

Comment: Thankful. I added your request

Comment: Thanks. but when i added that but the text is going down to the image, when i have addd that. Can you please let m know why? @FarhadBagherlo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153488/discussion-between-farhad-bagherlo-and-user3750720).

Comment: added the title before parent div

Comment: looks great :) Thanks a lot once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can make it
first you create two rows (divs) each one has two divs (floated to left) with 45% of width and the div at the right will have a margin left of 5%

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   body,html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .container{
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   }
   .row{
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   .box{
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .box-image{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid black;
   }
   .box-text{
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10%;
   }
   
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="box box-image">

    </div>
    <div class="box box-text">
     Delhi is a crowded city. There are very few rich people who travel by their
         own vehicles. The majority of the people cannot afford to hire a taxi or a 
         three-wheeler. They have to depend on D.T.C. buses, which are the cheapest 
         mode of conveyance. D.T.C. buses are like blood capillaries.
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="box box-image">

    </div>
    <div class="box box-text">
     Delhi is a crowded city. There are very few rich people who travel by their
         own vehicles. The majority of the people cannot afford to hire a taxi or a 
         three-wheeler. They have to depend on D.T.C. buses, which are the cheapest 
         mode of conveyance. D.T.C. buses are like blood capillaries.
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#wraper{
display:block;
background:gray;
padding:10px;
width:100%;
}
#wraper #left,#wraper #right{
display:inline-block;
width:46%;
background:#fff;
margin:1%;
padding:1%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>

            <div id="wraper">
                <div id="left">
                         Delhi is a crowded city. There are very few rich people who travel by their
                         own vehicles. The majority of the people cannot afford to hire a taxi or a 
                         three-wheeler. They have to depend on D.T.C. buses, which are the cheapest 
                         mode of conveyance. D.T.C. buses are like blood capillaries.
                </div><div id="right">
                         Delhi is a crowded city. There are very few rich people who travel by their
                         own vehicles. The majority of the people cannot afford to hire a taxi or a 
                         three-wheeler. They have to depend on D.T.C. buses, which are the cheapest 
                         mode of conveyance. D.T.C. buses are like blood capillaries.
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

is this you want??

Answer (score -2):

you just have to use position property of CSS. this is for those who are basic in CSS... using position absolute you can place any object any where